# Kernel Modules not showing up in android Kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, android-source, kernel-module

Hi im pretty new to android/Linux kernel module creating and Ive been trying to get a simple hello module to work using this guide: https://abdullahyousafzaii.wordpress.com/2015/08/02/how-to-write-a-kernel-module-for-android/

As far as i can tell Ive been able to compile the module correctly with the aosp.
however when i look into /system/lib/modules/ on adb shell I dont see any of the driver modules and instead have this:

```
optee.ko       readme.txt  rk29-ipp.ko.3.0.101+ 
optee_armtz.ko rk29-ipp.ko rk29-ipp.ko.3.0.36+
```

my guess is that the modules are being compressed into packages that the android kernel uses.
is there a config to prevent this from happening?
or 
am I going about this the wrong way?

the board im using is the rk3399 with arm64 processors

Comment: What does lsmod give you?

Comment: an empty list:
Module                  Size  Used by

Comment: @Dan What happens when you insmod the driver?

Comment: If lsmod gives you an empty list, your kernel modules are not inserted. Either you didn't insert them (using insmod or modprobe) or they failed to initialize. Try inserting them again, and use dmesg to see log messages.

Comment: insmod the module works correctly. perhaps i wasnt clear. im trying to compile this module with the rest of the AOSP. and im trying to figure out where all these drivers are compiled and saved/run.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping your module (hello.c) in another directory like **drivers/misc** in the kernel. Then add `obj-m += hello.o` to the **drivers/misc/Makefile** in the kernel directory. Run a clean build and let me know if the .ko is present in /system/lib/modules/ on the board when you flash the new system.img

And you have to include `insmod /system/lib/modules/hello.ko` in **/system/core/rootdir/init.rc** file for the module to be autoloaded when the board boots up.

Comment: This does not respond to the actual question.  Four days before you posted this response, the asker explained in a comment that they have been able to manually load the module.  The question is about getting it included in the system image and presumably automatically loaded.

Comment: Edited the answer for getting the module included in the system image and automatically loaded